# Is std::any supported in MSVC 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c++17, stdany

I try to compile a piece of code with:

```
cl /c /std:c++latest /Gm- /sdl /Zc:inline /RTC1 /Oy /MDd /FA /EHs main.cxx
```

but I get this error:

```
error C2039: 'any': is not a member of 'std'
```

and I wonder how (if possible) can I get to have this feature. I don't see anything about it on their sites but knowing how much time they take to update them maybe it can be done

Comment: Perhaps [`std::experimental::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any)? Or use [Boost any](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/any.html)?

Comment: Did you include ```<any>``` in order to see if it works?

Comment: I supposed I didn't have to but I guess `std` should have given it away

Comment: As I can I see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/) it is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `<any>` has shipped with every release of VS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

It is, but one has to make sure that the correct c++ version is used.

Right click the project and under `Properties->C/C++->Language->C++ Language Standard` make sure it is set to the correct one.